# How can I access Sorcery in my RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, sorcery

Sorcery authentication gem: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery

Sorcery's creator provides an example Rails app with Sorcery test helpers included in its Test::Unit functional tests: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery-example-app/blob/master/test/functional/users_controller_test.rb

```
# Test::Unit functional test example
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @user = users(:noam)
  end

  test "should show user" do
    login_user
    get :show, :id => @user.to_param
    assert_response :success
  end
```

But I can't figure out how to get `login_user` to work in my RSpec controller specs.

```
/gems/sorcery-0.7.5/lib/sorcery/test_helpers/rails.rb:7:in `login_user': 
undefined method `auto_login' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Here's the relevant code in the Sorcery gem regarding the above error:
https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/test_helpers/rails.rb

```
module Sorcery
  module TestHelpers
    module Rails
      # logins a user and calls all callbacks
      def login_user(user = nil)
        user ||= @user
        @controller.send(:auto_login,user)
        @controller.send(:after_login!,user,[user.send(user.sorcery_config.username_attribute_names.first),'secret'])
      end

      def logout_user
        @controller.send(:logout)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## UPDATE:

As per Sorcery's documentation "[Testing in Rails 3](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Testing-rails-3)", I have indeed added `include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails` to my `spec_helper.rb`.

The Sorcery test helper `login_user` acts on `@controller`, but I'm getting the error because `@controller` is `nil` in my controller spec. Here's my spec:

```
#spec/controllers/forums_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe ForumsController do
  render_views

  describe 'GET new' do
    describe 'when guest' do
      it 'should deny and redirect' do
        get :new
        response.should redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end

    describe 'when admin' do
      p @controller #=> nil
      @user = User.create!(username: "Test", password: "secret", email: "test@test.com")
      login_user # <--------------- where the error occurs
      it 'should resolve' do
        get :new
        response.should render_template(:new)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FWIW, I spent a lot of time looking for an answer to this problem. I am using Capybara and RSpec.  As it turns out, you need to login manually to using Sorcery to get the login to work.

I've created a Gist on creating integration tests with Sorcery/Rspec/Capybara here:
https://gist.github.com/2359120/9989c14af19a48ba726240d030c414b882b96a8a

Comment: Good stuff. Accepted this answer instead of my weak little quitter's club answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the Sorcery test helpers in your spec_helper

```
    include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails
```

See the sorcery wiki : https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Testing-rails-3

In the example rails app, this is done at https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery-example-app/blob/master/test/test_helper.rb#L13

### Updated

Do you have any other Controller specs in the same folder which pass successfully ?
RSpec usually mixes in the required stuff for controller testing for the specs in "spec/controllers" folder.

You could try explicitly marking this as a controller spec by writing

```
describe ForumsController, :type => :controller do
```

Comment: I updated my post to reflect that I have made that change.

Right, I did do that so far. It appears that SOrcery expects a `@controller` to be available from the controller spec. `@controller` is nil in my controller spec. I'm currently looking up if RSpec either doesn't provide `@controller` or if it somehow can't tell if my spec is a controller spec. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your user creation and login into a before(:each) block as follows:

```
describe 'when admin' do
  before(:each) do
    @user = User.create!(username: "Test", password: "secret", email: "test@test.com")
    login_user
  end

  it 'should resolve' do
    get :new
    response.should render_template(:new)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For new application in Rails 7.0.0 I fixed this problem by adding:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb

config.include ::Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller
```

and then I could use method from Sorcery without defining my own:

```
# spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe RegistrationsController, type: :controller do
   let(:current_user) { nil }

   before do
      login_user(current_user) if current_user
   end

   describe "when user is logged in" do
      let(:current_user) { create(:user) }
      it "action new redirects to root" do
         get :new

         expect(subject).to redirect_to(root_path)
         expect(flash[:notice]).to eq(I18n.t("registration.new.already_logged_in"))
      end
   end
end
```

Adding just ::Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails couldn't find the login_user method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I've just experienced this dilemma myself and drawing from the input from danneu, diwalak and Birdlevitator (in this thead: [rail3/rspec/devise: rspec controller test fails unless I add a dummy=subject.current_user.inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508707)) I think I can see a solution.

I've been working with a standard rails 3 rspec generated resource from the 'rails generate scaffold' command. Here's the controller rspec file after I modified it to work with a sorcery login:

```
require 'spec_helper'

# This spec was generated by rspec-rails when you ran the scaffold generator.
# It demonstrates how one might use RSpec to specify the controller code that
# was generated by Rails when you ran the scaffold generator.
#
# It assumes that the implementation code is generated by the rails scaffold
# generator.  If you are using any extension libraries to generate different
# controller code, this generated spec may or may not pass.
#
# It only uses APIs available in rails and/or rspec-rails.  There are a number
# of tools you can use to make these specs even more expressive, but we're
# sticking to rails and rspec-rails APIs to keep things simple and stable.
#
# Compared to earlier versions of this generator, there is very limited use of
# stubs and message expectations in this spec.  Stubs are only used when there
# is no simpler way to get a handle on the object needed for the example.
# Message expectations are only used when there is no simpler way to specify
# that an instance is receiving a specific message.

describe RecordsController do

  before(:each) do
    @user = User.create!(forename: "Billy", surname: "Bob", username: "Test", password: "secret!1", email: "test@test.com")
    login_user
  end


  # This should return the minimal set of attributes required to create a valid
  # Record. As you add validations to Record, be sure to
  # update the return value of this method accordingly.
  def valid_attributes
    { :owner => 'Mr Blobby', :catagory => 'Index'}
  end

  # This should return the minimal set of values that should be in the session
  # in order to pass any filters (e.g. authentication) defined in
  # RecordsController. Be sure to keep this updated too.
  def valid_session
    {"warden.user.user.key" => session["warden.user.user.key"]}
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all records as @records" do
      record = Record.create! valid_attributes
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      assigns(:records).should eq([record])
    end
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    it "assigns the requested record as @record" do
      record = Record.create! valid_attributes
      get :show, {:id => record.to_param}, valid_session
      assigns(:record).should eq(record)
    end
  end

  describe "GET new" do
    it "assigns a new record as @record" do
      get :new, {}, valid_session
      assigns(:record).should be_a_new(Record)
    end
  end

  describe "GET edit" do
    it "assigns the requested record as @record" do
      record = Record.create! valid_attributes
      get :edit, {:id => record.to_param}, valid_session
      assigns(:record).should eq(record)
    end
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Record" do
        expect {
          post :create, {:record => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        }.to change(Record, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created record as @record" do
        post :create, {:record => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        assigns(:record).should be_a(Record)
        assigns(:record).should be_persisted
      end

      it "redirects to the created record" do
        post :create, {:record => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        response.should redirect_to(Record.last)
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns a newly created but unsaved record as @record" do
        # Trigger the behavior that occurs when invalid params are submitted
        Record.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
        post :create, {:record => {}}, valid_session
        assigns(:record).should be_a_new(Record)
      end

      it "re-renders the 'new' template" do
        # Trigger the behavior that occurs when invalid params are submitted
        Record.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
        post :create, {:record => {}}, valid_session
        response.should render_template("new")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "PUT update" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested record" do
        record = Record.create! valid_attributes
        # Assuming there are no other records in the database, this
        # specifies that the Record created on the previous line
        # receives the :update_attributes message with whatever params are
        # submitted in the request.
        Record.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({'these' => 'params'})
        put :update, {:id => record.to_param, :record => {'these' => 'params'}}, valid_session
      end

      it "assigns the requested record as @record" do
        record = Record.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => record.to_param, :record => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        assigns(:record).should eq(record)
      end

      it "redirects to the record" do
        record = Record.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => record.to_param, :record => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        response.should redirect_to(record)
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns the record as @record" do
        record = Record.create! valid_attributes
        # Trigger the behavior that occurs when invalid params are submitted
        Record.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
        put :update, {:id => record.to_param, :record => {}}, valid_session
        assigns(:record).should eq(record)
      end

      it "re-renders the 'edit' template" do
        record = Record.create! valid_attributes
        # Trigger the behavior that occurs when invalid params are submitted
        Record.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
        put :update, {:id => record.to_param, :record => {}}, valid_session
        response.should render_template("edit")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "DELETE destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested record" do
      record = Record.create! valid_attributes
      expect {
        delete :destroy, {:id => record.to_param}, valid_session
      }.to change(Record, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "redirects to the records list" do
      record = Record.create! valid_attributes
      delete :destroy, {:id => record.to_param}, valid_session
      response.should redirect_to(records_url)
    end
  end

end
```

And a run down of the important bits:

This bit does the programmatic login (ignore the forename and surname attributes, they're specific to the solution I'm building):

```
before(:each) do
    @user = User.create!(forename: "Billy", surname: "Bob", username: "Test", password: "secret!1", email: "test@test.com")
    login_user
end
```

This bit holds session info/key data:

```
def valid_session
    {"warden.user.user.key" => session["warden.user.user.key"]}
end
```

As diwalak writes, we need to add this to the spec_help.rb file:

```
include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails
```

And that's it - worked for me anyhow :)