# RSpec and devise : cannot sign_in admin

Tags: rspec, devise

I am migrating my standart Rails unit tests to RSpec and i have problems with devise. All controller containing devise authentication are failing with RSpec.

I try to sign_in an admin in RSpec following the devise tutorial, without success :

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)

Here is what i tried :

/spec/controllers/ipad_tech_infos_controller_spec.rb

```
before :each do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create :admin
    sign_in @admin
end
```

/spec/support/devise.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

/spec/factories/admin.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin do
    email "abc@abc.com"
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation {|u| u.password}
  end
end
```

My model is not confirmable, all my controller spec are failing.

If i remove before_filter :authenticate_admin! then all my tests pass.

Can anybody help ?

Comment: add config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller to rails_helper.rb, it worked well with me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Likely culprit:** Make sure you're not setting the session explicitly in your controller specs.

For instance, if you're using the default Rspec scaffold generator, the generated controller specs pass along session parameters.

```
get :index, {}, valid_session
```

These are overwriting the session variables that Devise's helpers set to sign in with Warden. The simplest solution is to remove them:

```
get :index, {}
```

Alternatively, you could set the Warden session information in them manually, instead of using Devise's helpers.

Comment: Also, if your admin is nested in the user Factory you need to call it like this: `sign_in :user, @admin`, which means `sign_in(scope, resource)`

Answer (score 3):

You said "My model is not confirmable" so the following does not apply to you, but there is a subtlety here that others might miss, like I did (and wasted an hour).

Note in the RSpec/Devise How-To that vdaubry mentions above, it says if you do have the Devise "confirmable" module enabled in your model, then either you need to call `@admin.confirm!` right before `sign_in @admin`, or else make sure your factory sets a `confirmed_at` when it creates your `@admin`. If you don't do this, the `sign_in` call will silently fail and all the subsequent specs will act like you're not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what was causing this, but for me the solution was to add the method:

```
def valid_session
  {"warden.user.user.key" => session["warden.user.user.key"]}
end
```

Found here: 
[rail3/rspec/devise: rspec controller test fails unless I add a dummy=subject.current_user.inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508707/rail3-rspec-devise-rspec-controller-test-fails-unless-i-add-a-dummy-subject-cur)